# How do i skip comments with buffer reader?

Tags: java

I have written the following program to read from a file and skip comments, it works for single line comments, but not for multi line ones. Does anyone know why? I don't need to worry about "//" in Strings. And only java comments ie "//" and "/*     */"

code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class IfCounter2 
{   
    public static boolean lineAComment(String line)
    {
        if (line.contains("//"))    
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public static boolean multiLineCommentStart(String line)
    {
        if (line.contains("/*"))    
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public static boolean multiLineCommentEnd(String line)
    {
        if (line.contains("*/"))    
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        String fileName = args[0];

        int numArgs = args.length;

        int ifCount = 0;

        // create a new BufferReader
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        line = reader.readLine();
        // read from the text file
        boolean multiLineComment = false;

        while (( line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
          if (!multiLineCommentStart(line)) 
          {
            multiLineComment = true;
          }

          if (multiLineComment) {
            if (!multiLineCommentEnd(line)) 
            {
              multiLineComment = false;
            }
          }

          if (!lineAComment(line) && !multiLineComment) 
          {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append(ls);
          }
        }


        // create a new string with stringBuilder data
        String tempString = stringBuilder.toString();
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());

    } 
}
```

Comment: How are you using these methods? it would seem that the problem is in the code that implements this unless I misunderstand the question.

Comment: In the main just below the methods :)

Comment: Sorry, didnt see the scrollbar... :/

Comment: No problem. What do you think now that you see implementation?

Comment: I put my response as a comment on Matt's answer.

Comment: The reason it does not show up is that "!multiLineComment"[mlc] is just reversing the value of the boolean. It does not mean it is false, it means that if mlc = T then !mlc = F || if mlc = F then !mlc = T.

Comment: write some test cases. also you may have combinations of // /* and */ on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

You only set `multiLineComment` to true when `!multiLineCommentStart(line)` is true - that is, whenever the line does not contain `/*`.

Comment: So what is it exactly that needs to be changed?

Comment: It seems that the intention of `multiLineComment` is to track when you are in between the start and end of a multiline comment. So think about when it makes sense to flip that flag active - when should you start tracking that you are in a multiline comment? Hint: it is not when the line does not contain the multiline start.

Comment: So i should get rid of the "!" not. So then i start tracking it when the line begins with "/*" ?

Comment: @josh. pretty sure thats right. If you remove the "!" from your first two if statements (with the references to the multiLineComment methods), right now you are are setting your variable to the opposite value than you want.

Comment: @Andy. That gets rid of everything but the last */  (closing multi line) So close. Any idea why?

Comment: @josh. see the other thread. ... maybe should cut down comments here :P

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your code should look sth like this (untested)

```
    boolean multiLineComment = false;

    while (( line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
      if (multiLineCommentStart(line)) 
      {
        multiLineComment = true;
      }

      if (multiLineComment) {
        if (multiLineCommentEnd(line)) 
        {
          multiLineComment = false;
        }
      }

      if (!lineAComment(line) && (multiLineComment == false)) 
      {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
        stringBuilder.append(ls);
      }
    }
```

in that last if statement, you need to have an expression with your variable and a fixed

Answer (score 0):

Andy's answer is right on the money but needs a validation in last if  to make sure you are not counting */ as a valid line:

```
    boolean multiLineComment = false;

    while (( line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
      if (multiLineCommentStart(line)) 
      {
        multiLineComment = true;
      }

      if (multiLineComment) {
        if (multiLineCommentEnd(line)) 
        {
          multiLineComment = false;
        }
      }

      if (!lineAComment(line) && (multiLineComment == false) &&
           !multiLineCommentEnd(line) ) 
      {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
        stringBuilder.append(ls);
      }
    }
```